# How do I set a logic app in Azure to transfer files from blob storage to sharepoint based on the name?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Good morning all,

I'm trying to build a logic app, that will upload the files from Azure Blob Storage to Sharepoint. It was quite easy to do when all the files were supposed to be uploaded to one folder. I was asked to seperate them by the name. So, if a file contains 'dog' in the name, it should go to folder 1, but if a file contains 'cat' it should go to a different folder on Sharepoint, from the same blob storage.

I've tried to add a condition to the logic app, that if it's 'true' that 'name' contains 'dog', upload it to folder 1, if false, upload it to folder 2 (there is always a file containing either 'dog' or 'cat'), but it still uploaded all of them to the folder with 'false' result. Basically, when I ran the logic app, all the results were false, so the problem is with the condition itself, but as I'm new to this, I wasn't able to figure out, what exactly is failing. Below is the screenshot of the logic app to upload all the files to one folder, I'm not quite sure where to put the condition (I've tried to place it everywhere, same result) and how to configure it properly.

Working solution to upload everything to one folder

[image]

[image: Condition]

[image: Result]

Comment: Where’s the condition in your definition? The image shows the steps but if the condition is the problem, just show us the at step and the relevant expression .

Comment: @Skin I've uploaded the screenshots of the condition.

Comment: Yes but you haven’t showed the expression on the right hand side of the condition. Can you provide that? Not a screenshot though this time, provide the text. Also, can you provide an example filename you’re dealing with?

Comment: The right expression is the same as the left one, what I want to achieve is that if a word set in string is found, it does 'true' (going to folder 1) and if it's not found, it does 'false' (going to folder 2)

The file names I'm dealing with are [date],Library,[Time].csv or [date],Select,[Time].csv

I would like files containing Library go to Library folder and everything else go to Select (as there are only 2 file name types)

Comment: But having the right side of the condition the same as the left doesn't seem right.  What's inside the `string(..)` condition there?

Comment: String('Library')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the left hand side of the condition is the name of the blob, based on what you've said you want, the right hand side should literally be the word `Library` ... no expressions or anything else.

Your condition, in plain English, says ...

> If the name of the blob contains the word "Library", do the true side, else, do the false.

If you want to check for the word **Library** ignoring case, wrap the blob name in a `toLower()` expression and set the right hand side to be all lower case, like thus ... **library**

Comment: I tried to do it with no expression too, but it still uploaded everything to one folder, no matter the name...

Comment: She me the exact name of the blob, use a screenshot.  Also update your screenshot with the current condition step.

Comment: Thank you @Skin, I haven't realized that this is case sensitive... I added this to the condition and created another condition for word 'select' and it's working properly now! Once again big thank you! Have a great week.